Proof Feedback: Analytic Functions Have Isolated Roots
I am working through a proof of the following lemma in complex analysis and would appreciate feedback or suggestions for improvement:
Lemma:
If $f(z)$ is a non-zero analytic function, then $f(z)$ has isolated roots. Specifically, if $f(z_0) = 0$ for some $z_0$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in D_\epsilon(z_0) \setminus \{z_0\}$, where $D_\epsilon(z_0)$ is the open $\epsilon$-ball centered at $z_0$.
Proof:
The proof is by contradiction. Assume there exists a root $z_0$ of $f$ and a sequence $\{z_k\} \to z_0$ (i.e., $\lim_{k \to \infty} z_k = z_0$) such that $f(z_k) = 0$ for every $k$. This would contradict the lemma's claim.
Since $f$ is analytic, it can be expressed as a Taylor series around $z_0$:
$$
f(z) = f(z_0) + f'(z_0)(z - z_0) + \frac{f''(z_0)}{2}(z - z_0)^2 + \cdots = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!}(z - z_0)^k.
$$
Let $a_k = \frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!}$. By assumption, $f(z_0) = 0$, so $a_0 = 0$.
Suppose $m \geq 1$ is the smallest integer such that $a_m \neq 0$. Then we can write:
$$
f(z) = \sum_{k=m}^\infty a_k (z - z_0)^k = a_m (z - z_0)^m \left(1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_{k+m}}{a_m}(z - z_0)^k \right).
$$
Let $g(z - z_0) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_{k+m}}{a_m}(z - z_0)^k$. Then:
$$
f(z) = a_m (z - z_0)^m (1 + g(z - z_0)) = a_m (z - z_0)^m G(z),
$$
where $G(z) = 1 + g(z - z_0)$ is analytic and satisfies $G(z_0) = 1$.
However, by assumption, $f(z_k) = 0$ for all $k$, which implies:
$$
0 = a_m (z_k - z_0)^m G(z_k).
$$
Since $a_m \neq 0$ and $G(z_k) \neq 0$ for sufficiently small $|z_k - z_0|$, this leads to a contradiction because $(z_k - z_0)^m \neq 0$.
Thus, the roots of $f(z)$ are isolated.

Why do you say "$G(z_k) \neq 0$ for sufficiently small  $|z_k - z_0|$"?

You should mention why there is a smallest $m$ such that $a_m \neq 0$ and why for sufficiently large $k$, $G(z_k) \neq 0$. To be extra pedantic, you should also mention that your chosen sequence $(z_k)$ is such that $z_k \neq z_0$ for all sufficiently large $k$.

@DavideMasi, if $ |z_k - z_0| $ is sufficiently small, the series representation of $ G(z) $ near $ z_0 $ converges to a value that ensures $ G(z_k) \neq 0 $ due to the analytic nature of $ G(z) $. By considering the series' magnitude diminishing in $ B_\epsilon(z_0) $ for small $ \epsilon $, one can rigorously conclude that $ G(z) \neq 0 $ in this neighborhood, and hence the proof holds under these conditions.
